# How to fetch data from XML file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to get the value of `<Title>` from XML file with Perl. I tried with Twig but still value is not fetching.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Specification SchemaVersion="4.3">
<Title><![CDATA[Txt to fetch]]></Title>

#more tags here

</Specification>
```

Here the sample Perl code which I tried:

```
my $openXml=XML::Twig->new();
$openXml->parsefile($filepath);
foreach my $root($openXml->root->children('Specification')){
$title=$root->first_child('Title')->att('string');
}
```

I need to take the value from that Title tag.

Comment: show your code as well.

Comment: @Bruce I added my code in the question

Comment: Always use strict; use warnings; See https://perlmaven.com/always-use-strict-and-use-warnings

Comment: @Bruce I added that and I forgot to add it in the code here . then also output is not fetching

Comment: You're using the att() method, which means you are looking for the attribute "string" in the element "Title", as in <Title string="test">Text here</Title>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet should get the title text from the xml file.

```
my $filepath = "xml_file.xml";

my $openXml = XML::Twig->new();
$openXml->parsefile($filepath);
my $title = $openXml->root->first_child_text('Title');
say $title;
```